# Can't catch pickle error

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, pickle

I have a thread that constanlty waits for input via a socket. It receives things fine, but if I try to `pickle.loads` the string, then I receive an error. That would be an easy thing to catch, but this is the error it returns:

```
Exception in thread Listening to <socket._socketobject object at 0x232cd00> at ('127.0.0.1', 48774):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/[redacted]/Server.py", line 46, in Listen
    pickled = pickle.loads(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1382, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 958, in load_binfloat
    self.append(unpack('>d', self.read(8))[0])
error: unpack requires a string argument of length 8
```

I have tried and successfully caught this with a simple `try...except` check with no specifications, but I have no idea how to catch this 'error', as `pickle.struct.error` only works for a few of the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, turns out `struct.error` WAS the error that was not being caught...